# Python to .exe raises Exception: Versioning for this project requires either an sdist tarball

Tags: python, jira, cx-freeze

I'm trying to build an executable from Python files. I was able to correct most errors, but now I'm stuck with this one and I can't find out how to correct it. My program interacts with the Jira API.

I'm using Cx_Freeze to build the .exe with the following setup. py file :

```
import sys
import setuptools
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"includes": ["appdirs", "packaging.specifiers", 
                     "packaging.requirements", "setuptools.msvc", "jira"]}

setup(name="Quick", version="1.0", executables=[Executable("main.py")], 
      options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
      install_requires=['selenium', 'jira', 'cx_Freeze'])
```

I enter in command prompt: `python setup.py build` and get a folder named build as a result. It contains a main.exe program. When I launch it from command prompt I get this error :

> Exception: Versioning for this project requires either an sdist tarball, or access to an upstream git repository. It's also possible that there is a mismatch between the package name in setup.cfg and the argument given to pbr.version.VersionInfo. Project name jira was given, but was not able to be found.

I've tried to upgrade Jira, setuptools and disutils with pip but it didn't change anything.

I'm using Python 3.6.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No I gave up, but I would still be interested in the answer!

Answer (score 2):

I have finally gotten this working and thought I should share my results since there seem to be very few people using Jira and cx_Freeze together. It seems that cx_Freeze does not package Jira properly. Below is what I did to get my script working.

First, in setup.py, I included these packages:

```
packages = ["os", "sys", "atexit", "getpass", "subprocess", "datetime", "dateutil", "jira", "openpyxl", "appdirs", "packaging"]
```

Many of these are not necessary for everyone but jira, appdirs, and packaging helped me.

Then, after running `python setup.py build`, I copied:

```
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\idna
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\idna-2.6.dist-info
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\jira
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\jira-1.0.15.dist-info
```

into:

`build\exe.win32-3.6\lib` (the directory created by running setup.py) overwriting any conflicts.

This solved the problem for me. Let me know if you have any other issues.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this exception while importing *jira* in a PyDev project, which links the *jira* git clone as a *Project Reference*.

The workaround for me was to extend the PATH environment to include the git executable.

### Analyse

`pbr/packing.py - get_version()` raise

> Exception: Versioning for this project requires either an sdist tarball, or access to an upstream git repository. ...

when `_get_version_from_git()` returns *None* . This happens, when 
`pbr/git.py - _run_git_functions() - _git_is_installed()` does not find a git executable.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue when I tried to upload my code with packages on AWS lambda function. After multiple trial and errors, adding the `idna` packages along with the `jira` packages worked for me.

```
idna
idna-2.10.dist-info
jira
jira-2.0.0.dist-info
```

Comment: I'm also trying to get the jira library to work in lambda (Alexa skill). Can you please explain what you mean by "adding the idna packages along with the jira packages"? Thx!